# Attempted relative import in non-package error in current structure

Tags: python

I'm getting "Attempted relative import in non-package" in this import statement. Where is the issue?

```
from ..Resources.UniversalHelper.Helper import UniversalPageHelper
```

Structure:

```
project/
        __init__.py
        MainFiles/
                  __init__.py
                  Main.py (where this from statement is being called)
        Resources/
                 __init__.py
                 UniversalHelper/
                                 __init__.py
                                 Helper.py
```

Comment: Do you have `__init__` file?

Comment: Yes in current directory the root directory (..) and Resources directory. All those init files are empty though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: I know it's a duplicate, but the other question doesn't give a clear answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter that you've put `__init__.py` files in every directory. It seems to me, that importing `Main.py` is done by `import Main` somewhere or by running the script`python project/MainFiles/Main.py`.

`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` tells you, that `Main` is not loaded as part of a package structure. You need to import it as complete package like `import project.MainFiles.Main` or run it as module `python -m project.MainFiles.Main`.

If the last is your problem, you should also have a look into `__main__.py`.

Comment: yes, anytime you are running a main program deep in a project, you should be using `python -m`